# A tkinter button in frame2 cannot be enabled/disabled as python 3 says it's a 'NonType' object

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm relatively new to python 3.6. I was able to change the states of buttons in frame1 but not in frame2 as though the objects in frame2 are in a different namespace. Or is it? Would someone please help? Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Raffle():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("280x72")
        frame1 = Frame(master, height=1, background="steelblue")
        frame2 = Frame(master, height=1, background="powderblue")
        self.btnGet = Button(frame1, text="Get Entry", bg="slategray",
            fg="whitesmoke", command=self.cmd1)
        self.btnGet.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)        
        self.btnEnum = Button(frame1, text="Break Down", bg="slategray",
            fg="whitesmoke", state="disabled", command=self.cmd2)
        self.btnEnum.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
        self.shuf = Button(frame1, text="Shuffle", bg="slategray",
            fg="whitesmoke", state="disabled", command=self.cmd3)
        self.shuf.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
        self.quickWin = Button(frame1, text="Winners", bg="slategray",
            fg="whitesmoke", state="disabled", command=self.cmd4)        
        self.quickWin.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.reset = Button(frame2, text="Reset", bg="slategray",
            fg="whitesmoke", command=self.cmd5)
        self.reset.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=10)
        self.Draw = Button(frame2, text="Draw",
            bg="magenta", fg="yellow", state="disabled",
            command=self.cmd6).pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=X)
        frame2.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=X)

    def cmd1(self):
        self.btnEnum.configure({"state": "normal"})

    def cmd2(self):
        ab={self.btnGet:0,
            self.btnEnum:0,
            self.shuf:1,
            self.quickWin:1}
            #self.draw:1}
       self.able(ab)

    def cmd3(self):
        pass

    def cmd4(self):
        pass

    def cmd5(self):
        ab={self.btnGet:1,
            self.btnEnum:0,
            self.shuf:0,
            self.quickWin:0}
            #self.draw:0}
        self.able(ab)

    def cmd6(self):
        pass

    def able(self, dic):
        for widget in dic:
            if dic[widget]==0:
                widget.configure({"state": "disabled"}) #disables entry
            else:
                widget.configure({"state": "normal"}) #enables entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = Tk()
    app = Raffle(parent)
    parent.mainloop()
```

The buttons in frame1 are just fine, but not the 'draw' button in frame2 which I can't enable or disable. I commented the part referring to that button (draw) because it returns an error as a 'NonType' object. Will someone please help...

Answer (score 0):

whew! it was an easy fix after all. i just have to pack it in a different line.

```
self.Draw = Button(frame2, text="Draw",
    bg="magenta", fg="yellow", state="disabled", command=self.cmd6)
        self.draw.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=5)
```